# Get and remove value on checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, checkbox

I would like to make get and remove value on checkbok when user checked and unchecked the checkbox. The contents of the checked checkbox will appear in the list section as a picture here[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AfhD.png

The problem is that when one of the checkboxes is unchecked, all the lists in the "list approver" are deleted. So how to delete the only unchecked checkbox values ​​from the approver list?

here is my code :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
                                    <ol class="list-group" >
                                            <div class="card">
                                            <li class="list-group-item group-containers">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                <input onclick="checkBox(this)" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="approver" value="{{ $user->name }}">
                                                    <div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">
                                                        <img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-8">
                                                    <div class="">{{ $user->name }}</div>
                                                    <label for="" class="text-secondary">{{ $user->email }}</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </input>
                                            </li>
                                        </div>
                                    </ol>
                                    @endforeach
```

Here is the code that shows the selected checkbox content :

```
<div id="listUser"></div>
                        
                            <ol class="list-group" style="display:none">
                            <div class="card">
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">
                                            <img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-8">
                                        <div class="">{{ $users[0]->name }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                </div>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
```

And here is the javascript code :

```
function checkBox(cb){
    var text = document.getElementById("list");
    var inners = '<ol id="list" class="list-group">'+
                            '<div class="card">'+
                                '<li class="list-group-item">'+
                                    '<div class="row">'+
                                        '<div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">'+
                                            '<img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url("/assets/img/avatars/3.png") }}">'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="col-8">'+
                                        '<div class="">'+cb.value+'</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</li>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</ol>'
    if(cb.checked==true){
        //text.style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('listUser').innerHTML += inners;
    } else {
        // text.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('listUser').innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Any solution??

Comment: syntax error : `</input>` doesn't exist in HTML...

Comment: revise your code, your opening and closing tags are not consistent

Answer (score 0):

First the input type needs to be checkbox.
Second create an unique id for each OL to access the element on the page.
Third remove the element by accessing it through its id

Your code is corrected and i wish the works for your.

```
<?php $id=0; ?>
@foreach($users as $user)
<?php $id +=1; ?>
<ol class="list-group">
    <div class="card">
        <li class="list-group-item group-containers">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="checkBox(this)" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="approver"
                    value="{{ $user->name }}">
                <div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">
                    <img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="">{{ $user->name }}</div>
                    <label for="" class="text-secondary">{{ $user->email }}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
</ol>
@endforeach


<script>
    function checkBox(cb) {
        var inners = '<ol id="'+ cb.value +'" class="list-group">' +
            '<div class="card">' +
            '<li class="list-group-item">' +
            '<div class="row">' +
            '<div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">' +
            '<img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url("//3.png") }}">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-8">' +
            '<div class="">' + cb.value + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</li>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</ol>';

        if (cb.checked == true) {
            //text.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('listUser').innerHTML += inners;
        } else {
            // text.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(cb.value).remove();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkBox(cb,name){
var id =  'approver_' + name;
    var text = document.getElementById("list");
    var inners = '<ol id="list" class="list-group">'+
                            '<div class="card">'+
                                '<li class="list-group-item">'+
                                    '<div class="row">'+
                                        '<div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">'+
                                            '<img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url("/assets/img/avatars/3.png") }}">'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="col-8">'+
                                        '<div class="">'+cb.value+'</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</li>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</ol>'
    if(cb.checked==true){
        //text.style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('listUser').innerHTML += inners;
    } else {
        // text.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("listUser").innerHTML = "";
    }
}

@foreach($users as $user)
                                <ol class="list-group" >
                                        <div class="card">
                                        <li class="list-group-item group-containers">
                                            <div class="row">
                                            <input onclick="checkBox(this)" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="approver_"+ {{ $user->name }}  value="{{ $user->name }}">
                                                <div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">
                                                    <img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-8">
                                                <div class="">{{ $user->name }}</div>
                                                <label for="" class="text-secondary">{{ $user->email }}</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </input>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>
                                </ol>
                                @endforeach
```

Simply replace above code and check.
Note :1) id="approver_"+ {{ $user->name }} --for assigning dynamic id with username
2) var id =  'approver_' + name; -- for getting id

same question is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71233899/7204027

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).