# HTML uncheck checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

When I check the user's checkbox, the checked user is displayed on the List Approver as shown below.

[image]

My problem is if I uncheck the specific user's checkbox (e.g Lempi Olson), instead of removing Lempo Olson from the List Approver, it removes all of the user from the List Approver. I'm assuming that I should define it in the javascript code.

Here is the javascript code:

```
function checkBox(cb){
    var text = document.getElementById("list");
    var inners = '<ol id="list" class="list-group">'+
                            '<div class="card">'+
                                '<li class="list-group-item">'+
                                    '<div class="row">'+
                                        '<div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">'+
                                            '<img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url("/assets/img/avatars/3.png") }}">'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="col-8">'+
                                        '<div class="">'+cb.value+'</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</li>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</ol>'
    if(cb.checked==true){
        //text.style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('listUser').innerHTML += inners;
    } else {
        // text.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("listUser").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Here is the checkbox code:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
                                    <ol class="list-group" >
                                            <div class="card">
                                            <li class="list-group-item group-containers">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                <input onclick="checkBox(this)" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="approver" value="{{ $user->name }}">
                                                    <div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">
                                                        <img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-8">
                                                    <div class="">{{ $user->name }}</div>
                                                    <label for="" class="text-secondary">{{ $user->email }}</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </input>
                                            </li>
                                        </div>
                                    </ol>
                                    @endforeach
```

Any solutions?

Comment: does your checkboxes got same id? if yes that's the problem

Comment: I've updated the checkbox code to the question, please have a look

Comment: yep all of your checkbox has same id, you need to do something like this--- id="approver_1" for 1st checkbox, approver_2 for 2nd and so on

Comment: How do I differentiate the checkbox id because I uses foreach?

Comment: you can do this, `<input onclick="checkBox(this, {{$user->name}})" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="approver_{{$user->name}}" value="{{ $user->name }}">` and in your js code do this, `var id = "approver_"+username` and based on this `id` do operation

Comment: I've change my code but I don't quite understand how to do the operation based on the id because I'm new to javascript. Can you show me how?

Comment: Your HTML that you are creating there is invalid, you can not have `div` as child of `ol`. And why are you appending a new ordered list with just one item to begin with here? This should be _just_ the new item, and get appended to the already existing list element.

Comment: Another one of those account hoppers, who ask the same thing under multiple nicknames, huh? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230952/get-and-remove-value-on-checkbox

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to make each id unique to perform operation only the desired checkbox, to do that you can do this

```
    @foreach($users as $user)
                                    <ol class="list-group" >
                                            <div class="card">
                                            <li class="list-group-item group-containers">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                <input onclick="checkBox(this, {{ $user->name}})" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="approver_{{ $user->name}}" value="{{ $user->name }}">
                                                    <div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">
                                                        <img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-8">
                                                    <div class="">{{ $user->name }}</div>
                                                    <label for="" class="text-secondary">{{ $user->email }}</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </input>
                                            </li>
                                        </div>
                                    </ol>
@endforeach
```

After this make same changes in your js as well

```
    function checkBox(cb, username){
    var id = 'approver_'+username;
    var text = document.getElementById("list");
    var inners = '<ol id="list" class="list-group">'+
                            '<div class="card">'+
                                '<li class="list-group-item">'+
                                    '<div class="row">'+
                                        '<div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">'+
                                            '<img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url("/assets/img/avatars/3.png") }}">'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="col-8">'+
                                        '<div class="">'+id.value+'</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</li>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</ol>'
    if(id.checked==true){
        //text.style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('listUser').innerHTML += inners;
    } else {
        // text.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("listUser").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

there might be some errors here and there which you can fix.

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work, the checked user didn't show up to the list approver too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkBox(cb,name){
var id =  'approver_' + name;
    var text = document.getElementById("list");
    var inners = '<ol id="list" class="list-group">'+
                            '<div class="card">'+
                                '<li class="list-group-item">'+
                                    '<div class="row">'+
                                        '<div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">'+
                                            '<img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url("/assets/img/avatars/3.png") }}">'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="col-8">'+
                                        '<div class="">'+cb.value+'</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</li>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</ol>'
    if(cb.checked==true){
        //text.style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('listUser').innerHTML += inners;
    } else {
        // text.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("listUser").innerHTML = "";
    }
}

@foreach($users as $user)
                                <ol class="list-group" >
                                        <div class="card">
                                        <li class="list-group-item group-containers">
                                            <div class="row">
                                            <input onclick="checkBox(this,{{ $user->name}})" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="approver_"+ {{ $user->name }}  value="{{ $user->name }}">
                                                <div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">
                                                    <img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-8">
                                                <div class="">{{ $user->name }}</div>
                                                <label for="" class="text-secondary">{{ $user->email }}</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </input>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>
                                </ol>
                                @endforeach
```

Simply replace above code and check.
Note :1) id="approver_"+ {{ $user->name }} --for assigning dynamic id with username
2) var id =  'approver_' + name; -- for getting id
3) onclick="checkBox(this,{{ $user->name}})" --for passing username to function